# wso2 - WSF4J Service --deploy

Tags: wso2, msf4j

how to deploy a microservice writted by WSF4J?

like this:
Navigate to the /bin directory and run the following command to start the MSF4J server.
./carbon.sh

where is the carbon.sh ?

Answer (score 0):

MSF4J is a framework, and there is no server for that. Once you build your msf4j project, it creates a fat jar which can run alone, like this.

```
java -jar helloworld-*.jar
```

You can find the hello world sample [here](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/samples/helloworld).

**Edit:** Instead of the fat jar, you also can make it an OSGi bundle, and run it on Carbon 5 kernel with msf4j feature installed in it. For that go inside [resources directory](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/v2.1.0/samples/stockquote/bundle/resources), and build it as per the instructions, given in [here](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/v2.1.0/samples/stockquote/bundle). It will create a kernel server with msf4j in it. You can run that and deploy your microservice.

Comment: So, I would like to write the microservice like this:https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/samples/stockquote/bundle.  Then ,this sample is what to do?   I do it like the above http site and to write a microservice as a bundle

Comment: what is the differences between the fat jar mod and the bundle mode?

Comment: fat jar can run on its own. it includes all dependencies it needs. osgi bundle's required dependencies should be provided from an osgi environment. So you need a server to run that.

Comment: ok, If there are so many microservices ,how to deploy them with the fat jar mode?  each microservice has its own http port. If each jar was started ,it need many ports

Comment: @mike When you deploy a microservice in OSGi container you don't have to provide a port. The server port is determined at the container startup time. By default, it will be 9090. If you want to change that port or add more transport you can provide a config file to do that.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, as you say :deploy a microservice in OSGi container.   can you give me a sample that deploy a microservice in OSGi container?

Comment: @mike In OSGI environment you need to implement the Microservice interface from your service class. Then you can register your service implementation under Microservice interface either as an OSGi service component or directly using the bundle context. https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/blob/master/samples/stockquote/bundle/src/main/java/org/wso2/msf4j/stockquote/StockQuoteService.java#L52 we register microservice as a OSGi service component.

Comment: This will install the msf4j and other required features to the kernel and build up a product. You can find the product in the resources/target directory .Go to the target/wso2msf4j-/bin directory Then run the following command to start the MSF4J server.

./carbon.sh @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne  after clean install ,there is no this file, then how to do next? I do that with your official code

Comment: en ?by the way ,how to deploy a microservice with carbon? is there a sample?

Comment: Does `mvn clean install` complete without any errors? If yes, there should be the server zip inside target dir.

Comment: no any errors. however,there is no the server zip . Shoul I send you a screenshot by an e-mail?

Comment: Make it 2.1.0 and plz send a screenshot as well.

Comment: meanwhile,I modifed the pom.xml <msf4j.version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</msf4j.version> to 2.1.0.  because ,there is no depdency of 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT. does it matter ?

Comment: does  the http site copty screenshot ?Ｉtry and not successed. can you give me your e-mail address?

Comment: Is there another way that I use 4.4.1 carbon ws2oservers.sh to start my microservice bundle?

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Comment: You can't use carbon kernel 4.4.1 to deploy Mircoservices. As you have mentioned yu need to change the version to 2.1.0 and build.

Comment: yeah,I have changed the msf4j.verison to 2.1.0 ,But it is successful to build and there is no the server zip as you have mentioned

Comment: a part of the bundle's pom.xml . <properties>
        <carbon.messaging.version>1.0.6</carbon.messaging.version>  <carbon.transport.http.netty.version>2.1.4</carbon.transport.http.netty.version>  <carbon.metrics.version>2.0.0</carbon.metrics.version>
        <msf4j.version>2.1.0</msf4j.version>    <carbon.feature.plugin.version>2.1.0</carbon.feature.plugin.version>
        <carbon.kernel.version>5.1.0</carbon.kernel.version>
     <osgi.api.version>6.0.0</osgi.api.version>
 <carbon.jndi.version>1.0.0</carbon.jndi.version<carbon.deployment.version>5.0.0</carbon.deployment.version>

Comment: osgi> install file:D:\ProgramData\vianet2\v3\t\msf4j-master\samples\stockquote\bundle\target\stockquote-bundle-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
gogo: BundleException: Error reading bundle content.
what is the problem? @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Comment: In fact ,there is no   the zip wso2 MSF4J product in your official code .@ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Comment: There are some issues in the documentation. We will fix them in next releases. Please follow the below steps

1. Go to samples/stockquote/bundle/resource directory
2. Change the MSF4J version to 2.1.0 in the pom.xml
3. Run a mvn clean install
4. Go to target/wso2msf4j-2.1.0/osgi directory
5. Create a directory and names it as dropins
6. Copy your build stockquote bundle to that folder
7. Go to target/wso2msf4j-2.1.0/bin directory
8. Start the server using carbon.sh|bat script

Comment: if i exit from the osgi console after sh carbon.sh,the bundle which have started is stopped and disapper. That is to say that there is no microservice bundle.

Comment: The osgi console on my terminal shell can't be always opened.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Comment: another question,if I moved my bundle jar (ms3-2.1.0.jar) to dropins and ./carbon.sh ,there is no my bundle to installed.

Comment: When you put the bundle in dropins directory whenever server start it will be  installed. But if you install the bundle using OSGi console then it get removed in next start

Comment: I have not enough reputation. I put it the bundle jar in the dropins directory and sh carbon.sh . as you say,the bundle will be installed. But I use "lb" command to search my bundle and did not find it.  The following screen :65 ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.metrics.core_2.0.0
 
68 ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.core_2.0.0
69 ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter_2.0.0
70 ACTIVE      org.wso2.carbon.transport.http.netty_2.1.4
71 ACTIVE      reflections_0.9.10.wso2v1
72 ACTIVE      snakeyaml_1.16.0.wso2v1

Comment: by the way , what does  <carbon.component></carbon.componet> do? plz  can you explain the effect?

Comment: When you put the bundle in dropins directory whenever server start it will be installed.   I do  it  as you say, there is no my bundle yet. @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne